# Conditional Looping through Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, conditional-statements

I am running into an issue trying to loop through a dataframe. What I am trying to do is, based on the string in a specific column, give a new column a certain value, and repeat the row x amount of times. Else give that new column another value and repeat it y amount of times. However, when I try my code, I receive the following issue:

**ValueError: "array length 1 does not match index length 5" .**

I'm not sure what the issue with my logic is, and was wondering if anyone could show me how to solve this obstacle. I really appreciate the help!

Please find my code below:

```
for x in df['GP Line Item Code:']:
    if x == "PS-AFS":
        lens = 1
        clientDetails = pd.DataFrame({'Billing Date': np.repeat(df['Billed Date'], lens),
                    'Invoice #': np.repeat(df['GREAT PLAINS INV #'], lens),
                    'Customer #': np.repeat(df['GP Code'], lens),
                    'Customer Name': np.repeat(df['Client'], lens),
                    'Transaction ID': np.repeat(df['Quote ID'], lens),
                    'Description': np.repeat(df['Task'], lens),
                    'Department Group': np.repeat(df['Dept'], lens),
                    'Product Family': np.repeat(df['GP Line Item Code:'], lens),
                    'Revenue Type': np.repeat("Service", lens),
                    'Rev Rec Year': np.repeat(df['Billed Date'].dt.year, lens)
                   }
                  )
    else:
        lens = 12
        clientDetails = pd.DataFrame({'Billing Date': np.repeat(df['Billed Date'], lens),
                    'Invoice #': np.repeat(df['GREAT PLAINS INV #'], lens),
                    'Customer #': np.repeat(df['GP Code'], lens),
                    'Customer Name': np.repeat(df['Client'], lens),
                    'Transaction ID': np.repeat(df['Quote ID'], lens),
                    'Description': np.repeat(df['Task'], lens),
                    'Department Group': np.repeat(df['Dept'], lens),
                    'Product Family': np.repeat(df['GP Line Item Code:'], lens),
                    'Revenue Type': np.repeat("Maintenance", lens),
                    'Rev Rec Year': np.repeat(df['Billed Date'].dt.year, lens)
                   }
                  )
```

My logic is, for records in the dataframe, look at the GP Line Item Code. If the GP Line Item Code is PS-AFS, then repeat each record 1 time, and label Revenue type as Service. Else, for every other record that is not PS-AFS, so all my maintenance records, repeat each record 12 times, and label Revenue Type as Maintenance. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, I can't validate this code, but it should work:

```
mask = df['GP Line Item Code:'] == 'PS-AFS'

out = pd.concat([df.loc[mask].assign(Revenue_Type='Sevice')] +
                [df.loc[~mask].assign(Revenue_Type='Maintenance')]*12)
```

Then you can rename columns or create new columns.